# How to add my custom bus routes using google maps api?

Tags: android, google-maps, shortest-path, a-star

I want to know if its possible to use the google maps api in order to calculate the shortest paths between 2 points using only my custom bus routes? If it is please give me a hint.

Or should i instead implement the A* algoritm on my routes and find the shortest path this way?

Answer (score 0):

I know that Google has a feature called My Maps. It allows you to customise points on an existing map.

Alternatively, when you open Google maps and search for directions to a location, you have the option to create your own preferred route by dragging around. You can find tutorials online if you search "Custom route on google maps" in a search engine. I found this [article](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/57121/create-custom-route-google-maps/) useful.
It says that it is only available for desktop, but Google Maps (on iPhone at least) has now implemented this feature.

Comment: Please post more details about your answer . that would helps